# factor range as function variable in R

Tags: r, function, variables

I have code

```
ggplot(bywells[bywells$Well_N == "KRT3",], aes(x = Date_m)) +
geom_line(aes(y = QOM, colour = "Oil, m3/month"))
```

which draw chart. This code works without any errors. Now I would like to elaborate it in function where `bywells` is variable `data` and `"KRT3"` is variable `wellname`, but if I write like this

```
simple_fun <- function(data, wellname, ...)
{
   require("ggplot2", quietly=TRUE)
   ggplot(data[data$Well_N == "wellname",], aes(x = Date_m)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = QOM, colour = "Oil, m3/month"))
}
```

after executing function I get error message

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:QOM, Date_m
```

when I try

```
ggplot(data[wellname == Well_N %in% data,], aes(x = Date_m))
```

I get

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'Well_N' not found
```

Any hints how can I define it as a variable properly?

For example reproducibility I ad small chunk of data sample:

```
"Well_N";"Date_m";"QOM";"QWM";"QOMT";"BHP";"PRES";"QIW";"THPI";"QFM";"WCT"
"KRT3";2014-06-30;132;525;108;NA;NA;NA;NA;657;79
"KRT3";2014-07-30;36;120;29;NA;NA;NA;NA;156;76
"KRT3";2014-08-30;39;2.6;32.1;NA;NA;NA;NA;41.6;6.25
"KRT3";2014-09-30;211.274;749.362;174.070;NA;NA;NA;NA;960.636;78
"KRT3";2014-10-30;45;45;37.07;NA;NA;NA;NA;90;50
"KRT4";2014-08-30;108.37;1815.358;90.79;NA;NA;NA;NA;1923.73;94
"KRT4";2014-09-30;161.775;202.87;133;NA;NA;NA;NA;364;55
"KRT4";2014-10-30;30;1680;24;NA;NA;NA;NA;1710;98
"KRT4";2014-11-30;31.8;339;26;NA;NA;NA;NA;370.8;91
```

Type of `Well_N` is `factor`, `Date_m` is `POSIXct`, others are `num`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What is the point of `wellname` argument, if you're not using it?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, maybe I lost somewhere - I'm not a programmer. I just would like to realize that function can bee called as simple_fun(mydataframe, AnyWellName). In my data I have 93 levels of factor Well_N.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, is it more clear now?

Comment: Here are a few hints on how to make your question reproducible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example How do you run the function?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I added "required". Is it OK now? Function could be run mannually, or called by another function to go through all or range of factors and output saved as separate png or composed pdf file if several factor plots generated.

Comment: Read the thread I posted earlier. There are a lot of tips on how to provide us with data. Take in consideration that we are lazy beings.

Comment: Try using aes_string rather than aes for ggplot in function and call function with variable names as strings ("well1"). Google for aes_string and ggplot2

Comment: There is only one date in example data: 2014-06-30 . One cannot try a graph with that.

Comment: Take out the quotes around `"wellname"`. Otherwise `data[data$Well_N == "wellname",]` returns a `data.frame` of 0 rows.

Comment: @shadow, then I get error `Error in data$Well_N : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`
@mso, thanks for advice, I'll do some googling and inform on progress.

Comment: How are you calling the function? For me `simple_fun(bywells, "KRT3")` works. Of course `simple_fun("bywells", "KRT3")` would give me the same error you seem to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reproducible data (I've left only three columns which are needed, use function `dput` in your future questions):

```
bywells <-
structure(list(Well_N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("KRT3", "KRT4"), class = "factor"), Date_m = structure(c(16251, 
16281, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16404), class = "Date"), 
    QOM = c(132, 36, 39, 211.274, 45, 108.37, 161.775, 30, 31.8
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("Well_N", 
"Date_m", "QOM"))
```

Here is the call without the function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
qplot(x=Date_m, y=QOM, data = bywells %>% filter(Well_N == "KRT3"), geom="line")
```

Here is the function:

```
pfun <- function(data,wellname) {
    qplot(x=Date_m, y=QOM, data=data %>% filter(Well_N == wellname), geom="line")
}
```

with the corresponding call:

```
pfun(bywells,"KRT3")
```

Your error was to put the quotes on the variable `wellname` in the condition which filters the data. Also your colour setting is not ok, since there is no such color called "Oil, m3/month". Aim for English words such as "red", "blue", see `colors()` for more variants. Colour should be set outside aes argument in order for it to work.